# Row echelon form to solve this system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I want to use the row echelon form to solve this system:
$$
\begin{cases}
4x +2 -z= 0\\
y^2 -4 =0\\
2z -x =0
\end{cases}.
$$
I am confused by the second equation: if it was $y-4$ instead of $y^2 -4$, the matrix to reduce in row echelon form should have been
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0 & -1 &-2\\
0 &1 & 0 & 4\\
-1& 0 & 2& 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
but how to proceed when there is a quadratic term? Could anyone please help me?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) is for linear systems. Your system is not linear. However, you can make it linear: you have either $y=2$ or $y=-2$.

Comment: Consider only the first and third equations which are linear, for row-reducing, whereas the second is not.

Comment: As Bernard suggests: use the row echelon form for the equations 1 and 3. The second can be solved independently, giving y=4 or y=-4.

Comment: Thank you everyone!!

Comment: You can't solve quadratic systems of equations with Gaussian elimination unless you are working with finite fields. Take $y=2$ or $y=-2$, then your solutions are $(x,y,z)= (-2/7,2,-1/7)$ and $(x,y,z)= (-2/7,-2,-1/7)$ respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This started out as a comment, but then it got too long.

---

Okay, so the comments pretty much answer the specific question directly, so allow me to address the general case, for posterity's sake.

> What do we do when we see a nonlinear term in a system of linear equations?

Well, it helps to consider that "linear" is a relative term; really we ought to say that an equation is linear *with respect to* some particular variable. For instance $x^2-2y=-3$ is linear in $x^2$, but not $x$.

With this in mind let's look at an example. Consider the following system of equations:

$$\begin{cases}
5x + 2y^2 = 3\\
2x-4z = 0\\
-3x + y^2 +z = 0
\end{cases}$$

Notice that the variable $y$ only ever appears in the form of $y^2$, so we can treat $y^2$ as its own variable (feel free to replace '$y^2$' with '$u$', if it helps). Doing so, we get the augmented matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
5&2&0&|&3\\
2&0&-4&|&0\\
-3&1&1&|&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Which we can reduce to get

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&|&\frac3{10}\\
0&1&0&|&\frac34\\
0&0&1&|&\frac3{20}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So $x=\frac3{10}$, $y^2=\frac34$, and $z=\frac3{20}$, whence $y=\pm\sqrt\frac34$.

What's really going to bake your noodle later on is: could we still do this with a system of polynomial equations?

Answer (score 1):

Since $y$ appears in only one equation, the fact that we have $y^2$ is not a problem. You can just note $Y=y^2$, and then you get the system :
$$\begin{cases} 4x +2 -z= 0\\ Y -4 =0\\ 2z -x =0
\end{cases}$$